# Как перевести время в UNIX на 2 часа

Tags: php, mysql, unix

Есть переменная `$time` - в ней лежит время формата `[Y-m-d H:i:s]`, нужно перевести это время в UNIX, добавить 2 часа и перевести обратно в формат `[Y-m-d H:i:s]`

Comment: это не домашка, в бд лежит дата со временем и мне нужно чтобы к ней добавлялось 2 часа

Comment: какая база? mysql postgres?

Comment: @Saidolim mysql, ячейка форматом datetime

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Это можно на уровне базы сделать

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD(poleDateTime, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) chislo 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение на PHP (по тегу поста):

```
$date = (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: где здесь исходная переменная `$time`?